# Sharepoint columns in document library - Conditional Logic

Tags: document-library

I've got two columns in a document library. If value x is selected from the first column, I want the second column to display. If any value other than x is selected the second column (a choice column) shouldn't display. How do I do that from within a Sharepoint library?

I am using SharePoint 2010....

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.
Caroline

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little simple script in the page which simply sets the class for column 2 to ms-hidden until the condition is met. You can add script like this into a Content Editor Web Part or add it directly to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the free [Connected Lookup Field](https://web.archive.org/web/20140524074919/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/leonidly/archive/2007/06/24/connected-lookup-field.aspx) or [SPFields](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/multiple-column-lookup-field-for-sharepoint/). There are a few commercial solutions available as well [such as this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20130404054026/http://www.sharepointboost.com:80/cascaded-lookup.html).